# Matching constructor not found (C++) in HardwareStore Class

Tags: c++, constructor, matching

I have been working on a hardware store application, where there is a HardwareRecordclass that stores information about each object in a store (ex: nuts, bolts, screws, and so forth).

The information is stored in a ".dat" file, but this is not important right now.

Here's my declaration of this class:

```
//  Definition of HardwareRecord class

#ifndef __Initialize_Hardware_Store_File__HardwareRecord__
#define __Initialize_Hardware_Store_File__HardwareRecord__

#include <iostream>

class HardwareRecord
{


public:

HardwareRecord(const int& account=0,const std::string& name="",const std::string& description="",const double& price=0.0); //constructor
HardwareRecord operator=(HardwareRecord&);

//'set' and 'get' functions
void setAccountNumber(int);
int getAccountNumber() const;

void setName(std::string);
std::string getName() const;

void setPrice(double);
double getPrice() const;

void setDescription(std::string);
std::string getDescription() const;

void wipeRecord(); //set everything to blank


private:
int myAccountNumber;
std::string myName;
std::string myDescription;
double myPrice;
};

#endif /* defined(__Initialize_Hardware_Store_File__HardwareRecord__) */
```

Here's my class definition:

```
//  Implementation of HardwareRecord class definition

#include <iostream>
#include "HardwareRecord.h"

using namespace std;

HardwareRecord HardwareRecord::operator=(HardwareRecord & aRecord)
{
    this->myAccountNumber=aRecord.myAccountNumber;
    this->myName=aRecord.myName;
    this->myDescription=aRecord.myDescription;
    this->myPrice=aRecord.myPrice;

    return *this; //allow for cascaded overloading
}

HardwareRecord::HardwareRecord(const int& account,const string& name,const string&     
description,const double& price)
{
    setAccountNumber(account);
    setName(name);
    setPrice(price);
    setDescription(description);
}



void HardwareRecord::wipeRecord()
{
   setAccountNumber(0);
   setName("");
   setPrice(0);
   setDescription("");
} 

void HardwareRecord::setAccountNumber(int num)
{
    if (num < 0)
    {
        throw invalid_argument("The account number is not in the valid range (greater or equal to 0)");
    }
    else
    {
        myAccountNumber=num;
    }
}

int HardwareRecord::getAccountNumber() const
{
    return myAccountNumber;
}

void HardwareRecord::setName(string name)
{

    myName=name;

}

string HardwareRecord::getName() const
{
    return myName;
}

void HardwareRecord::setPrice(double price)
{
    if (price < 0)
    {
        throw invalid_argument("The price can not be less than zero");
    }
    else
    {
        myPrice=price;
    }
}

double HardwareRecord::getPrice() const
{
    return myPrice;
}

void HardwareRecord::setDescription(string description)
{
   this->myDescription=description;
}

string HardwareRecord::getDescription() const
{
    return myDescription;
}
```

The class described is supposed to be used in the following main.cpp file:

```
//  Application that models a store's record of inventory

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include "HardwareRecord.h" //HardwareRecord definition
using namespace std;

//enumeration of choices
enum Choices {WIPE_RECORDS,UPDATE,LIST,PRINT,DELETE,NEW,END,LAST};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& op,const Choices& choices)
{
    //print the string corresponding to the value of enum type Choices
    string output="";
    switch (choices)
    {
        case WIPE_RECORDS:
            output = "wipe records";
            break;

        case UPDATE:
            output = "update records";
            break;

        case LIST:
            output = "list records";
            break;

        case PRINT:
            output = "print records";
            break;

        case DELETE:
            output = "delete records";
            break;

        case NEW:
            output = "add new record";
            break;

        case END:
            output = "terminate application";
            break;

        case LAST:
            output = "an option used to iterate over the values in the Choice enumeration";
            break;

        default:
            cerr << "Error. invalid value is read";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;


    }

    op << output; //print output
    return op;
}

//prototype of helper functions
int enterChoice();
void wipeRecords(fstream&);
void updateRecord(fstream&);
void listRecords(fstream&);
void createTextFile(fstream&);
void deleteRecord(fstream&);
void newRecord(fstream&);

int main()
{
    //open file for reading and writinbg
    fstream outRecord ("HardwareRecord.dat",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);

    //exit program if fstream cannot open file
    if (!outRecord)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int choice; //user's choice

    //enable user to specify action
    while ((choice=enterChoice()) !=END)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case WIPE_RECORDS: //wipe all records clean
                wipeRecords(outRecord);
                break;

            case UPDATE: //update a record
                updateRecord(outRecord);
                break;

            case LIST: //list all current records
                listRecords(outRecord);
                break;

            case PRINT: //print a record
                createTextFile(outRecord);
                break;

            case DELETE: //delete a record
                deleteRecord(outRecord);
                break;

            case NEW: //add a new record (if space allows)
                newRecord(outRecord);
                break;

            default: //display error if user does not select valid choice
                cerr << "Incorrect choice" << endl;
        }

        outRecord.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}

//enable user to input menu choice
int enterChoice()
{
    //display avaliable options
    cout << "\nEnter your choice:\n"<< endl;
    Choices aChoice;
    for (int c=WIPE_RECORDS; c < LAST; c++)
    {
        aChoice= (Choices) c;
        cout << c << " - " << aChoice << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n?: ";
    int menuChoice;
    cin >> menuChoice;
    return menuChoice;

}

void wipeRecords(fstream& theFile)
{
    HardwareRecord temp;
    for (int i=0; i < 100;i++)
    {
        //convert record from binary and assign to temp
        //make temp "wipe itself"
    }
}
```

Yes, I realize that many of the functions are defined by prototype, but are not actually declared. This will be done later after this very problem described shortly afterwards is fixed. Please direct your attention to the following piece of code, from this very file:

```
void wipeRecords(fstream& theFile)
{
    HardwareRecord temp; //Here's where the error occurs: No Matching constructor!
    for (int i=0; i < 100;i++)
    {
        //convert record from binary and assign to temp
        //make temp "wipe itself"
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to compile this project on my Mac (I use xCode), I get the following error for the line that is commented. The error is "No matching constructor for initialization of 'HardwareRecord'". However, I provide default values for the constructor of a HardwareRecord object, so the line

```
HardwareRecord temp;
```

should initialize without any problems.

What is going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: @Chnossos: There's a constructor with all arguments having defaults. Same thing.

Comment: I don't get the error you reported with your code.

Comment: Which compiler and version?  It appears that the compiler isn't accepting the code, although it should.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem. In your constructor, you use an `std::string&`, however, you *never include `<string>` in your code!*

Along with some other errors, compiling with G++ gives you:

> prog.cpp:46:57: error: ‘string’ does not name a type

This may invalidate your default constructor.

Comment: If this is the problem then `std::string myName;` *should* also throw an error. Although it is not guaranteed that any behaviour after the first error message is valid. So this is still the most likely answer so far :)

Answer (score -3):

You're attempting to use a default constructor.

```
HardwareRecord temp;
```

But you've declared a constructor that takes arguments, as well as an assignment operator.  The act of declaring a constructor that takes arguments means that the compiler will not generate a default constructor for you.  So if you want one you'll have to declare one yourself OR use the constructor you've created.

EDIT

My answer above is NOT correct as the OP has provided defaults for all specified arguments.

In the case I specified the compiler will state something like:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo()’
```

But with defaults specified it will compile.

Small test:

-- foo.h

```
class Foo
{
  private:
    int _i;

  public:
    Foo( int i );
};
```

-- foo.cpp

```
 #include "foo.h"

 Foo::Foo( int i )
 : _i( i )
 {
 }

 int main()
 {
   Foo foo;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Quote from Fred Larson: "There's a constructor with all arguments having defaults. Same thing"

Comment: @deviantfan Why the downvote?  And what's the point of your quote.  The answer I've provided is correct.

Comment: Gcc says too that your answer is wrong, wait until I quote the standard... btw., you shoulnd´t assume who downvoted.

Comment: N3242 12.1.5: A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that can be called without an argument. "Can be called without", not "has no arguments".

Answer (score -3):

HardwareRecord class should have default constructor, e.g., like this:

```
class HardwareRecord {
  public:
    HardwareRecord() : myAccountNumber(0),
                       myName(""),
                       myDescription(""),
                       myPrice(0.0f) {}
...
};
```

Your current constructor with default parameter values doesn't seem to be regarded as a 'Default Constructor'.

Comment: No, this wasn´t me. Go on and ask a mod if you really want to. But it´s wrong nonetheless.